# Reinstalling OpenOffice.org

Tags: 10.10, 64-bit, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I removed OpenOffice.org  and installed LibreOffice about a month ago. LibreOffice cannot spell-check and i would like to go back. However Ubuntu gives me dependency problems and I cannot reinstall the OOO suite.

Comment: I had the same issue when I installed LibreOffice via the PPA. Try installing the hunspell package (whichever language you need) - that should at least get LibreOffice working again.

Comment: You may also try to get spell-cecking fixed by using Open Office modules

Comment: [LibreOffice can do spell checking.](http://imgur.com/WenFr.png)

Comment: yes thanks but i still would like to solve the dependency problems and reinstall OOO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Firstly, go to the OpenOffice website: http://download.openoffice.org/other.html and download the Linux **.deb** file.

2 - Once you have done that, extract the .deb file, **OOo_3.3.0_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz** then you'll see a file called **OOO330_m20_native_packed-1_en-GB.9567**

3 - You can remove the existing version of OpenOffice if you wish with this command:

**sudo apt-get remove openoffice*.***

4 - Copy and paste OOO330_m20_native_packed-1_en-GB.9567 onto the desktop then open Terminal and paste this command:

**sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/OOO330_m20_native_packed-1_en-GB.9567/DEBS/*.deb**

5 - Then paste this command:

**sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/OOO330_m20_native_packed-1_en-GB.9567/DEBS/desktop-integration/openoffice.org3.3-debian-menus_3.3-9556_all.deb**

Once you've done that you'll find OpenOffice 3.3.0 in Office.

If you want to remove LibreOffice then the command to copy and paste into Terminal is

**sudo apt-get remove libreoffice*.***